# Entity Relation Extraction Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: python, parsing, stanford-nlp, pycorenlp

Please am trying to  do a relationship extraction from a parse sentence bunch of text in a pdf.
I used the stanford coreNLP with the the python pycorenlp to parse the sentence now I want to extract the Subject Verb and Object from this parse tree

Here is a sample of my Data :
'Mark Robert is the founder of 3trucks. 3trucks was founded in 2010'

Here is what I want as output:
('Mark Robert', founder,'3trucks')
('3truck', founded '2010')

Here is an example of the text and the code

```
import nltk
import re
from pycorenlp import *

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP("http://localhost:9000/")

text = 'Mark Robert is the founder of 3trucks. 3trucks was founded in 2010'

output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse',
"timeout": "50000",
'outputFormat': 'json'

 })

print(output['sentences'][0]['parse'])
print('------------------------------')
print(output['sentences'][1]['parse'])`
```

my code output:

```
(ROOT
(S
(NP (NNP Mark) (NNP Robert))
(VP (VBZ is)
  (NP
    (NP (DT the) (NN founder))
    (PP (IN of)
      (NP (NNS 3trucks)))))
(. .)))
------------------------------
(ROOT
(S
(NP (NNS 3trucks))
(VP (VBD was)
  (VP (VBN founded)
    (PP (IN in)
      (NP (CD 2010)))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can include 'openie' in the list of annotators. Openie will also form groups of triplets, which is required as the list. Also remember to limit the output to 3.

```
output = nlp.annotate(s, properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie",
                            "outputFormat": "json",
                             "openie.triple.strict":"true",
                             "openie.max_entailments_per_clause":"1"})
```

Post which you can add the output as per your need.

```
result = [output["sentences"][0]["openie"] for item in output]
for i in result:
    for rel in i:
        relationSent=rel['subject'],rel['relation'],rel['object']
        print(relationset)
```

Hope this helps.